# Decay multiple functions inside caller method

Tags: c++, performance, templates

This question is related mostly to an issue of large code maintenance and re-usability that I have. I have a several classes which have a method like this:

```
void MyClassX::Draw(){

   ///Some large chunk of code#1 here


   ///Another large chunk of code#2 goes here


   ///Another large chunk of code#3 goes here

}


void MyClassY::Draw(){

   ///Some large chunk of code#1 here


   ///Another large chunk of code#2 goes here

}
```

The difference between the variations of that method are that some of those chunks of code are optional in different classes.
Now, it may sound silly, but because that method does some performance critical real-time processing (3D rendering). I don't use functions for those code chunks and don't want to wrap them with those as I am trying to reduce a number of functions calls in general. What I want is to define those functions in some block (for example using #define) and just declare those instead of the whole code chunks in the appropriate places inside `void Draw()`. I wouldn't want to use pre-processor for it because it is hard to edit such a code (no proper error hinting or debugging). Another option I thought would be inline functions. But because the compiler doesn't guarantee to inline I am not sure this way is efficient. Are there other tricks? Maybe through C++ templates usage? Can I force some function body to decay inside caller method?

P.S. Because of performance consideration I also don't use inheritance for those classes as it basically also could solve that problem by defining all those chunks as functions in the base class. Also inside void `Draw()` I try to reduce conditional branching to a bare minimum.

Comment: Why close???What's wrong with the question?

Comment: You should empirically test the different ways of writing this. Avoid guessing. For instance, it could be faster to put the chunks into different functions rather than inline it all if that results in better cache performance (less code means lower cache pressure). This is why `inline`-ing is at the compiler's discretion. Similarly, branch prediction may mitigate the performance impact of conditional branching. If performance is that critical you really need to measure, measure, measure.

Comment: That's correct but I am asking here if there are more ways of guaranteeing expansion of a method than those I listed.

Comment: And I'm saying you're trying really, really hard to avoid the most direct solution of using `inline` functions. Why is that? "Trying to reduce a number of function calls in general" sounds like optimization advice from 20 years ago, similar to, say, loop unrolling. It's not necessarily good advice these days. You should do an A-B comparison and *measure* compiler `inline`-ing vs. manual inlining to see if you're really getting a net gain out of doing it by hand.

Comment: So you mean that on today's hardware functions calls are not issue anymore?Could you then write some consistent answer to my question?Thanks.

Comment: I added a lot of hedge words on purpose. Inlining is "not necessarily" good advice. It "could be" faster to avoid it. There are lots of tradeoffs. Avoiding a function call instruction saves some cycles, yes. But having more code will cause more cache pressure. If the additional code causes a cache miss, you're now worse off. BTW, I'm writing this in comments because I'm not really answering your question directly, I'm just saying you should verify that you really need to do what you're asking.

Comment: Ok,let's assume that performance is a separate problem.How do I expand method's body without using macros or "inline"?How can I force that expansion to actually happen?There is no any C++ 11 template trick of doing that?

Comment: @MichaelIV I don't know your situation fully, but it does sound an awful lot like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @MichaelIV It's not so much that function call overhead is negligible, but just that compilers tend to do a good enough job without our help. Where it tends to need our help more in micro-efficiency is like efficient vectorization, multithreading, memory layouts that utilize everything in a cache line before evicting it, utilizing the stack more, etc. But if you imagine like an extreme case where you just had your entire program logic in one giant function, an optimizer doesn't know that some rare case/exceptional loop which occurs when the user provides input to abort is any less special...

Comment: ... than, say, your main path tracer logic, so it might do a poor job with register allocation. When you create these things in separate functions, you establish barriers for things like register allocation so that your common case execution branches are optimized separately from those rare case ones. So I've found, as others suggested, that it can often be helpful to figure out what not to inline than figuring out what to inline so that I can push that common case code into a spotlight. Optimizers have rarely screwed me over on the latter case, but I have screwed myself over with the former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ways to force inline functions on some compilers, such as `__forceinline` on MSVC or `__attribute__((always_inline))` on GCC. It's very compiler-specific but you can guarantee it with a few caveats. There I recommend checking your compiler documentation as well as getting used to analyzing disassembly to some broad level (enough to recognize function calls, e.g., which is fairly easy because you can trace through it with a debugger and notice when it's branching).

That said, I really think you might be looking at this wrong. I could be wrong, and perhaps you have very special needs I've not encountered before, but I'm in a performance-critical field where, aside from correctness, efficiency is often directly proportional to the perceived quality of the product (I'm also in 3D, including path tracing).

I'm used to working with a profiler in hand and I've learned to take the idea of trusting the optimizer with a grain of salt. There's things optimizers and standard libs don't do so well, and I'm used to doing things like rolling my own memory allocators with considerable gains.

But I have never, ever encountered a case in my numerous profiling sessions where the compiler did a poor job with respect to the overhead of function calls. I have seen optimizers have hiccups and do a poor job with instruction selection or register allocation, where rewriting the code a certain way which shouldn't actually help did help emit more efficient assembly. That includes turning some big chunks of code into more functions, which you wouldn't think should aid performance but helped the compiler with those two areas (register allocation and instruction selection).

One of the more helpful things I've found in optimization is that optimizers might be great, but they don't understand what kind of user input is going to be received at runtime. That's a key aspect of common case execution that only someone who understands the design of the product can anticipate. So one of the things I've found is that putting the rare case branches of code into separate, unlined functions so that the logic isn't all inlined in one giant blob actually helps somehow (didn't investigate the disassembly for all of these cases, just noticed improvements in times). I think it's just kind of helping the compiler not look at all of your code as kind of a flat playing field, helping it to optimize a bit more selectively/locally since there's only so many registers, for example, and putting everything in one gigantic function might confuse the optimizer as to which part needs more attention.

That said, I have found it generally helpful to work with more centralized code during profiling and optimization. That's not because having more centralized code in a large function actually speeds things up, but because it's easier to work with something a bit less structured when you're trying to squeeze out micro-level efficiencies. It's easier to impose more structure after you've micro-tuned things than to be trying to unravel it before you go through those exhaustive profiling sessions, so it can be helpful to write code in this way sometimes and sacrifice some neatness and structure for big blocks of code. But the benefit there is more in the ease of changing that kind of code after profiling it and gaining that efficiency knowledge in hindsight to help organize the code; I've never actually seen such code actually make things faster.

So I really think you would do better not to focus on inlining that much and leave it more up to the optimizer. There's usually better things to optimize with clearer gains even at the smallest of micro-efficiency levels.